# Authenticating Blazor app with B2C with ui_locales query string

Tags: c#, azure, blazor

Currently the sign in page in Azure B2C can be translated to the customer’s browser language by selecting Enable language customization on the Languages tab of the User Flow in Azure AB B2C. All good.

In our Blazor app, user can select another language of their choice and we’d like to be able to show the sign in page in the language selected by the user.

Does anyone know how to set the ui_locales value from within the Blazor app so that the sign in page would include this ui_locales query string in it? I was thinking if MSAL would provide an option to inject a query string to the request, but I didn't find any info related to that.